# Sharepoint search returns different results from different computers

Tags: sharepoint, wss, sharepoint-search

There is a strange behavior with my WSS3. I have list with a couple of elements which have a dash in their name, for instance XXX-111 or YYY-22. If I search for this elements on my computer it correctly returns the element. However if I make the same search on another computer (with the same SharePoint account of course) the result is empty. What is going on? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your web front ends are out of sync.

RDP to each of your front ends, and place a JPG in the 12 hive.  The picture should be the number of the web front end respectively.

In the list/document library's dispform.aspx file, use SPD to reference the JPG from the 12 hive using an  HTML tag.  When you view the page, it will show you what web front end you're looking at.

This way you can see which web front end has the syncing problem.  If...that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry if it took so long but I was on holiday, anyway we only have one front end so I am not sure what you mean.